# How to incapsulate logic of updating profile?

Tags: laravel

There are some user roles: doctor, clinic.

Also here is a controller method that accepts the userid and array of field for updating.

I get the user role by userid, then I need to use specific realization for updating this user data.

How to organize it more encapsulated and flexible?

I have idea to create abstract class and some implementation classes for each roles.

```
abstract class UpdateProfile {
    abstract validate(Request $request);
    abstract update();
}
```

But I am doubt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Template Method pattern is a great solution to your problem. You can read about its implementation [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/php/example)

example of implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractProfileEditor
{
    protected array $validationRules;

    abstract protected function prepareAttrs(array $attrs): array;

    /**
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    public function update(Model $profile, array $attrs): Model
    {
        $validatedAttrs = $this->validate($attrs);
        $validatedAttrs = $this->prepareAttrs($validatedAttrs);

        if (!$profile->update($validatedAttrs)) {
            // throw profile updating exception
        }

        return $profile;
    }

    /**
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    protected function validate(array $attrs): array
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($attrs, $this->validationRules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }

        return $validator->validated();
    }
}

class ClinicProfileEditor extends AbstractProfileEditor
{
    protected array $validationRules = [
        'clinic_name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:50'
    ];

    protected function prepareAttrs(array $attrs): array
    {
        // logic for clinic

        return $attrs;
    }
}

class DoctorProfileEditor extends AbstractProfileEditor
{
    protected array $validationRules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:10|max:200'
    ];

    protected function prepareAttrs(array $attrs): array
    {
        // logic for assistant

        return $attrs;
    }
}
```

In your `AppServiceProvider` -> `register()`

```
$this->app->bind(AbstractProfileEditor::class, static function () {
    switch (Auth::user()->role->name) {
        case 'doctor':
            return DoctorProfileEditor::class;
        case 'clinic':
            return ClinicProfileEditor::class;
        default:
            // throw profile editor not found exception
    }
});
```

Your controller method:

```
public function update(Request $request, AbstractProfileEditor $profileEditor)
{
    $profile = $profileEditor->update($request->user()->profile, $request->all());

    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Maybe Laravel has from the box  something for that?

Comment: No, this is business logic. you have to write it yourself. I added an example of implementation close to your case

Comment: What do you think about create a separate resources Doctor, Patient and implement own update method in controller? May be I overcomplicated?

Comment: I asked this in a new question